# tail command is not working (tomcat9) to run the logs

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I configured cron-tab scheduler to my system(LINUX),
so
that for every 5 hours the tomcat will going to shutdown and it will restart again.

The scheduler is working fine and i am logging the all the output into a text file.

Scheduler configuration is:

```
0 */5 * * 1,2,3 /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/restart.sh > /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/log.txt  2>&1
```

and my restart.sh file contains following information.

```
/home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/bin/shutdown.sh
/home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/bin/catalina.sh run
```

While running the tomcat(with scheduler) i am trying to run the tomact logs by using tail command . Then it will shows that the tomcat is in shotdown position.

tail command which i am using is

```
tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

Why the tail command shows shutdown information?

Comment: try `tail -F logs/catalina.out` instead

Comment: Thanks for response. same error i am getting when  i try with -F

Comment: What do you see, and what are you expecting to see in catalina.out ? This is the default log, it shows both startup and shutdown messages.